# Getting column index when clicking on editable GRID

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an editable grid created in Ext. I added checkbox model on it.

I want column index, when I click on any cell in grid, and also by clicking on cell. The entire row should not be selected.

Comment: Take a look at this section of the asking help guide. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why dont you use itemclick event listener and handle your code there

Comment: The question is very low quality and confusing... I tried to improve it the way I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

```
itemclick: function(data, record, item, index, e, eOpts){ 
        **var position = data.getPositionByEvent(e);**
        ColumnIndex = position.column;
```

by this, ColumnIndex of specific cell can be obtained.